# Show a Qt window that does not take focus

Tags: c++, qt

How could I create a window with Qt that the user can interact with (i.e., clicking buttons in the window) but that does not otherwise change or take focus?

Use case: I have a `QLineEdit` and I would like to show an additional "manipulator" popup when the `QLineEdit` gains focus. This manipulator popup might include buttons for tasks like converting to uppercase/lowercase or such.

I can get it to work if I set the focus policy for all the manipulator's child widgets to `Qt::NoFocus` but this feels a little odd because I literally have to iterate over them.

I am wondering if there is a way to disable focus to a widget altogether, like `setEnabled()` would disable/enable all the child widgets.

Below are some findings so far.

## QCompleter

The `QCompleter` does something very similar to a `QLineEdit`, showing a `QListView` popup. It does so by setting the `QListView`'s parent to 0 so it becomes a window, and it sets the `Qt::Popup` window flags so it will be frameless. Finally it sets `focusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus)` to prevent it from taking over the focus from the associated `QLineEdit`.

This is trivial because there is only one single widget that needs its focus policy set to `Qt::NoFocus`.

## QDateTimeEdit

In `QDateTimeEdit` something similar is done. The popup there, however, actually takes focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such a widget out of the box. However, it can be done in this way:

**Header file:**

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QFocusEvent>

class LineEdit : public QLineEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    LineEdit(QWidget *parent) : QLineEdit(parent)
    { }

    void focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *event) override
    {
        QLineEdit::focusInEvent(event);
        emit focusIn();
    }

    void focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *event) override
    {
        QLineEdit::focusOutEvent(event);
        emit focusOut();
    }

signals:
    void focusIn();
    void focusOut();
};

class ExtendedLineEdit : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ExtendedLineEdit(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event) override;

private:
    void setupWidget();

    LineEdit *lineEdit;
    QWidget *showableWidget;
    QPushButton *toUppercaseButton;
    QPushButton *toLowercaseButton;

    QWidget *parent;

};
```

**Source file:**

```
#include "ExtendedLineEdit.h"
#include <QPoint>

ExtendedLineEdit::ExtendedLineEdit(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , parent(parent)
{
    setupWidget();
}

bool ExtendedLineEdit::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(obj)
    if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease ||
        event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress ||
        event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick)
    {
        lineEdit->setFocus();
    }
    return false;
}

void ExtendedLineEdit::setupWidget()
{
    auto mainLayout = new QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout::Direction::TopToBottom, this);
    this->setLayout(mainLayout);

    lineEdit = new LineEdit(this);
    mainLayout->addWidget(lineEdit);

    showableWidget = new QWidget(parent);
    showableWidget->setAutoFillBackground(true);
    showableWidget->setPalette(QPalette(QPalette::Background, Qt::white));
    showableWidget->hide();

    auto bottomLayout = new QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout::Direction::LeftToRight, showableWidget);
    showableWidget->setLayout(bottomLayout);

    toUppercaseButton = new QPushButton("to uppercase", this);
    toUppercaseButton->installEventFilter(this);
    connect(toUppercaseButton, &QPushButton::clicked,
            this, [&]{
       lineEdit->setText(lineEdit->text().toUpper());
    });

    toLowercaseButton = new QPushButton("to lowercase", this);
    toLowercaseButton->installEventFilter(this);
    connect(toLowercaseButton, &QPushButton::clicked,
            this, [&]{
       lineEdit->setText(lineEdit->text().toLower());
    });

    bottomLayout->addWidget(toUppercaseButton);
    bottomLayout->addWidget(toLowercaseButton);

    connect(lineEdit, &LineEdit::focusIn,
            this, [&]{
            auto size = lineEdit->size();
            auto position = QWidget::mapTo(parent, lineEdit->pos());

            showableWidget->setGeometry(position.x(),
                                        position.y() + size.height(),
                                        size.width(),
                                        40);
            showableWidget->show();

    });

    connect(lineEdit, &LineEdit::focusOut,
            showableWidget, &QWidget::hide);
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I honestly feel a little bad given the overwhelming effort you've put into your answer... yet it is still a minute off my original intention. What I am looking for is something like a small popup that shows up next to the line edit when it gains focus (like the `QCompleter`). This way it would also work if the line edit is incorporated into an item view (as a delegate), for example.

Comment: @Kamajii - no problem, I enjoy writing answers here. The answer is slightly changed. If you still interested in solving this problem, you can go with that example anywhere you want (since it is obviously "raw").